# vue component used inside ElementUI message box can't access the vuex store

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to use [elementUI message box](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/message-box) together with a simple component.
the component should simply access the store and present the username:

```
// 'MyCmp.vue'
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Name: {{fullname}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    fullname() {
      return this.$store.getters.fullname;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

but the problem is that i can see the hard coded string: "Name" inside the box  but can't access the `$store` because `this` is `undefined`. here is the complete code for my message box:

```
showMessageBox(userAction) {
  const h = this.$createElement;
  MessageBox.prompt(this.$t("insertEmail"), {
    message: h(myCmp, {key: this.key++}))
  })
    .then(({ value }) => {
      console.log("in");
      MessageBox.message({
        type: "success",
        message: "yourEmailIs" + value
      });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("error");
      MessageBox.message({
        type: "info",
        message: "cancel"
      });
    });
}
```

i expected it to work according to the docs and this official docs [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhiyang/ezmhq2ef)
they supply, which i followed during the implementation.
any idea why cant i access the `$store`/ `this` is undefined inside the component?

**UPDATE:**
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/al_sade/a2b7L4v0/25/)

Comment: Is showMessageBox a component method of MyCmp or a store action?

Comment: showMessageBox  is a method implemented inside the component that contains a button, which once clicked should present the message box. so not exactly but i guess you can call it the parent component of the message box, which in turn contains `MyCmp`. Lets assume i only have `App.vue` except for `MyCmp` and so showMEssageBox would be in `App.vue` component

Comment: Have you tried instead of `{{ user.fullname }}` just `{{ fullname }}`, i don't see anywhere where a `user` variable is declared.

Comment: OK, and where in the method do you want to use $store/this? Do you just need it for the purpose of getting fullname?

Comment: @jordan sorry edited my question, i tried to simplify things as much as possible. `this` is undefined though so it wouldn't change the end result.

Comment: @v-moe i simplified things but i do want to do more than just reading information from the `$store` from within  `MyCmp` . i also need to `dispatch` actions

Comment: How are you referencing your custom component? The example in the JsFiddle adds it as a global component, although it isn't shown in your question.

Comment: i import the component : `import MyCmp from "./components/MyCmp"

Comment: Have you tried completely recreating the component structure used in the JsFiddle, or even simply assigning the component variable from it's object value, as i've done here: https://jsfiddle.net/5p4aqgfd/

Comment: @jordan uploaded a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/al_sade/a2b7L4v0/25/